# Snakemake and cloud formation cluster error with local scratch space

Tags: aws-cloudformation, snakemake

I am having a problem using local scratch space on cfncluster and snakemake at the same time. My strategy is to write data  to local scratch for each node in the cluster and then move the data to the NFS partition.
Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

snakemake 4.0.0, cfncluster

```
 /shared/bin/bin/snakemake --rerun-incomplete  -s /shared/scripts/sra_to_fa_cluster.py -j 1 -p --latency-wait 20  -k  -c " qsub -cwd -V" -F 

/shared/dbGAP/sra_toolkit/sratoolkit.2.8.2-1-ubuntu64/bin/fastq-dump  --split-files --gzip  --outdir /scratch/   /shared/dbGAP/sras2/test/SRR2135300.sra
Waiting at most 20 seconds for missing files.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/shared/bin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 319, in check_and_touch_output
    wait_for_files(expanded_output, latency_wait=wait)
  File "/shared/bin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/io.py", line 395, in wait_for_files
    latency_wait, "\n".join(get_missing())))
OSError: Missing files after 20 seconds:
/scratch/SRR2135300_2.fastq.gz

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/shared/bin/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/shared/bin/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/shared/bin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/executors.py", line 647, in _wait_for_jobs
    active_job.callback(active_job.job)
  File "/shared/bin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/scheduler.py", line 287, in _proceed
    self.get_executor(job).handle_job_success(job)
  File "/shared/bin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/executors.py", line 549, in handle_job_success
    super().handle_job_success(job, upload_remote=False)
  File "/shared/bin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/executors.py", line 178, in handle_job_success
    ignore_missing_output=ignore_missing_output)
  File "/shared/bin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/snakemake/dag.py", line 323, in check_and_touch_output
    "wait time with --latency-wait.", rule=job.rule)
snakemake.exceptions.MissingOutputException: Missing files after 20 seconds:
/scratch/SRR2135300_2.fastq.gz
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
```

This is similar to the error reported here: 
https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/462/unhandled-missingoutputexception-in

Snakemake script is as follows:

```
   rule all:
           input:expand("/shared/dbGAP/sras2/fastq.gz/{sample}_{end}.fastq.gz", 
  sample=SAMPLES, end=END)

rule move:
    input: left="/scratch/{sample}_1.fastq.gz", right="/scratch/{sample}_2.fastq.gz"
    output: left="/shared/dbGAP/sras2/fastq.gz/{sample}_1.fastq.gz", right="/shared/dbGAP/sras2/fastq.gz/{sample}_2.fastq.gz"
    shell: "rsync --remove-source-files  -av {input.left} {output.left}; rsync --remove-source-files  -av {input.right} {output.right};"


rule get_fastq_files_from_sra_file:
    input: sras="/shared/dbGAP/sras2/test/{sample}.sra"
    output: left="/scratch/{sample}_1.fastq.gz", right="/scratch/{sample}_2.fastq.gz"
    shell: "/shared/dbGAP/sra_toolkit/sratoolkit.2.8.2-1-ubuntu64/bin/fastq-dump  --split-files --gzip  --outdir /scratch/   {input}"
```

My feeling is that snakemake cannot "see" the scratch on the nodes, so it returns it as missing, but I am not sure how to solve this issue.

Comment: So, do you mean that this error occurs in the master process of Snakemake? I guess that node does not share the scratch with the node where the rule gets executed.

Comment: If that is the case, simply move your rsync command into the rule `get_fastq_files_from_sra_file`.